# Saxon vs. XMLSpy, root template

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a stylesheet that I need to use via XMLSpy and via Saxon. It uses no input file. Instead, it generates the whole output by itself.
Saxon gives me the option to execute the sheet without a source file: -it:root, eg.
Then I need to have a named template called  "root":

```
<xsl:template name="root">
    ....
</xsl:template>
```

But XMLSpy needs a

```
<xsl:template match "/">
    my stuff
</xsl:template>
```

I cannot let XMLSpy start at "root". (well, i would not know how...)

So I thought, i'd do:

```
<xsl:template name="root">
    <xsl:apply-template select="/"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match "/">
    my stuff
</xsl:template>
```

to make everybody happy. But only XMLSpy is happy.
From Perl, I do:

`java.exe -jar E:\\Saxon\\saxon9he.jar -it:root -o:package.opf -xsl:package.xslt`

Saxon says:
XPDY0002: Finding root of tree: the context item is absent.

So: what can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure, that for XSLT 2.0, it should be possible with XMLSpy to start with a named template but I can't tell you how to do that, ask in a user form on the altova.com web site. The command line interface of Altova's AltovaXML simply uses `/n root` as a command line option. As for trying to run the XSLT without the need to start with a named template, I would do that the way you had to do it with XSLT 1.0, namely providing a dummy XML input and then doing `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:call-template name="root"/></xsl:template>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="root">
  stuff
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can invoke the code either by supplying a dummy documents in apply-templates mode, or by starting at the named template "root".